# I need to take the option chosen from the <select> tag as a php variable to a function

Tags: php, function

```
<select id='vaccines'>
     <?php
        include realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Classes/Controllers/DoctorController.php');
        $names=DoctorController:: getVCName();
        foreach ($names as $namesAvailable) {
           echo "<option value='$namesAvailable[nameID]'>$namesAvailable[names]</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
```

I want to take that value and store it in a php variable to send to a function in another page, is it possible?

Comment: is it in a form or what,how do you submit this value?

Comment: add a name attribute to select tag before you submit and after that you assigned that value to global or session variable or pass that value as request parameter to get that page

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in a number of ways;

You could create a form, send that form back to a PHP script and use `$_POST` or some other method to fetch your data from the request.

You could also use Ajax and send the data to the PHP script via a `change` event on the `select` element (e.g. via `JQuery`).

There are numerous other ways to do this, but if you read up on those two, you probably find that these are the easy ways to do this.

After you did that, you can ask questions about actually implementing this if something is not clear to you.

Comment: I did it but I am only facing one problem now 
this is what I wrote in the action of the form
/Classes/Controllers/DoctorController.php?action=editVC  but I also need to send along with that a variable, how is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If the select is under a form tag, you will need to give it a `name` in order to get its value on the next page, which the value got posted.

```
<form action="yourNextPage.php" method="post">
<select name='vaccines' id='vaccines'>
  <?php
       include realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Classes/Controllers/DoctorController.php');
       $names=DoctorController:: getVCName();
       foreach ($names as $namesAvailable) {
           echo "<option value='$namesAvailable[nameID]'>$namesAvailable[names]</option>";
       }
  ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="sub" />

</form>
```

In **yournextPage.php**:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
$selectedvaccine = $_POST['vaccines'];
echo $selectedvaccine;
?>
```

Comment: it is not working, but this method redirects me to another page, I only want to pass the value to a function in another page and not be redirected. I have spent sometime searching for a solution after this did not work but did not have any luck

Comment: You'll need ajax for this, then.